# integer to TimeStamp in Python

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

Consider a `pd.Series` which contains a date column with integers, e.g. 01052012. What is the best way to convert this?

Example:

```
        tDate
0    20040915
1    20041020
2    20041117
3    20041222
4    20050119
..        ...
203  20210818
204  20210915
205  20211020
206  20211117
207  20211222
```

Using `pd.TimeStamp(x)` outputs:

```
>> pd.Timestamp(x.data.tDate[0])
Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.020040915')
```

I can do loop over each element and do the following, but it's most likely not a good practice:

```
y = x.values[0][0])[:4]
m = x.values[0][0])[4:6]
d = x.values[0][0])[6:]
pd.Timestamp(int(y),int(m),int(d))
```

Comment: to be clear, `20040915` should result in `2004-09-15`?

Comment: `pd.datetime(x.data.tDate, format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')`, considering tDate is a pandas series column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first cast the integer as a string and use the strptime method of the datetime module.

Something like this:

```
In [3]: s = pd.Series([20040915,20041020])

In [4]: s = s.map(str).map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d'))

In [5]: s
Out[5]:
0   2004-09-15
1   2004-10-20
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

As mentioned in the comments,

```
In [6]: s = pd.Series([20040915,20041020])

In [7]: pd.to_datetime(s.astype(str))
Out[7]:
0   2004-09-15
1   2004-10-20
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

will give the same result and is likely faster with large series.

Comment: no need fo map, lambda or datetime here, simply `pd.to_datetime(s.astype(str))`

Comment: I took this as an accepted comment since it gives you more control

Answer (score 3):

this should work as well

```
 df['tDate'] = df['tDate'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(str(x)))
```

Another option will be to just cast the whole column like this

```
 df['tDate'] = df['tDate'].astype(str).astype('datetime64')
```

Comment: no need for the apply/lambda... `pd.to_datetime(s.astype(str))` allows for adjustments if needed and is slightly more readable.

Comment: This is slightly faster than the answer by wpercy

Comment: You might need `.astype("datetime64[ms]")` or `.astype("datetime64[ns]")` in newer versions